# Unable to get FileStream Length with After Insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trigger, filestream, filetable

I asked this question on [StackOverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458780/unable-to-get-computed-value-with-after-insert-trigger), but it mostly received comments about the use of variables and no answer. I program mainly in VB.Net, so my T-SQL knowledge is limited. The reason I'm populating a `FileProperties` table (especially for non-transactional file copies) is for building relational data that will work with EF6. I'm hopeful exposure here may shed some light on my issue.

I'm using the `FileTables` feature and have setup a trigger to populate a `FileProperties` table whenever a file is copied to the SQL Server file share.

I'm trying to grab the file size (`cached_file_size`), and I get a value of zero. I set up the trigger the same way a standard `FileTable` does using `DATALENTGH(file_stream)`. The code below is using the inserted tables' `file_stream`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FileTable_Insert_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[Files]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0)
        RETURN;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED)
        RETURN;

    DECLARE @s_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            @fs VARBINARY(MAX),
            @nm NVARCHAR(255),
            @fp NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @cfs BIGINT,
            @ft NVARCHAR(255);
 
    SELECT @s_id = ins.stream_id FROM inserted ins;
    SELECT @fs = ins.file_stream FROM inserted ins;
    SELECT @nm = ins.name FROM inserted ins;
    SELECT @fp = ins.file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath() FROM inserted ins;  
    SELECT @ft = ins.file_type FROM inserted ins;
    SELECT @cfs = DATALENGTH(@fs);

    INSERT INTO [FileProperties] (stream_id, [name], filepath, file_type,
                                  cached_file_size, DateAdded, UserID)
    VALUES (@s_id, @nm, @fp, @ft,
            @cfs, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1);
END
```

I've also tried grabbing the computed value directly from the `FileTable`:

```
SELECT @cfs = Files_1.cached_file_size 
FROM [dbo].Files AS Files_1 
WHERE Files_1.stream_id = @s_id;
```

Still getting zero. What am I missing here? Thank you.

*Note:* I tried playing around with getting the `DATALENGTH` of other values such as the `name (@nm)` and `stream_id (@s_id)` and I do get the values correctly.

Comment: The reason no one attempted to answer your question on SO is because your trigger is so fundamentally flawed that no one is going to look beyond that until you fix it. Once you have corrected your trigger such that its correct then people will look at the issues - assuming you still have them.

Comment: Also as a best practice, don't use obscure variable names such as `@nm`, `@fp` etc, that just makes it harder to read. Use full words.

Comment: And the FileTable row comes with a pre-populated `cached_file_size` - why not use that?

Comment: @DaleK - instead of telling me how flawed it is, why not edit and fix it?  You did the same thing on SO despite me telling you I'm a novice and this trigger is based off a tutorial I followed.  This place is supposed to exist for learning, not criticism. Furthermore, I state the reason I'm doing it in my text - EF6 doesn't support FileTables.

Comment: Don't confuse terse with personal. None of the advice provided is intended as a criticism, its the fundamental information you need to proceed. If you follow said advice you will learn and your code will be better - which one assumes you want? You were pointed to the *correct* tutorial on SO which allows you to correct your trigger. Neither site is for people to do it for you - its to provide you with the pointers so you can do it yourself. And once you have removed the obvious issues, people will then be able to focus on the real issues.

Comment: And if EF6 doesn't support FileTables, how are you carrying out your inserts? (Note I didn't ask why you are doing it, I asked why you aren't using the already existing `cached_file_size` column of `Inserted`).

Comment: I've been to the official docs for using the inserted table (prior to you posting the link) and it's not clear to me where my fundamental error resides.  I have never written a trigger, but this does work for single and multiple files aside from giving me the cached_file_size.  If I grab the cached_file_size from the inserted table, it returns a zero value as well.  So I figured I would compute it then based on the inserted file_stream.

Comment: Also, my inserts are performed non-transactionally through the file system.

Comment: Is the `cached_file_size` column populated at all in your `File` table (when you select from it outside of the trigger, just ad-hocly)?

Comment: @J.D. - Yes, I can simply query it with a SELECT statement.

Comment: @merlot Sorry and to be clear, there's a value in it when you do query it directly?

Comment: @J.D. Correct, there is a value.

Comment: "it's not clear to me where my fundamental error resides" - your fundamental error is writing code that only works for a single row in `Inserted`. `Inserted` can have 0-N rows and any trigger code needs to handle that because you have no way to restrict an insert to a single row. Secondly in your case you don't need variables at all, just `insert into MyTable (Col1, Col2 ...) select Value1, Value2 from Inserted`.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe 'FileTable' non-transactional actions fire a trigger for each file being copied, updated or deleted. Otherwise, how could you explain both single and multiple files properly firing the trigger and populating the table correctly? As for the the variables, I don't understand how using them is fundamentally wrong. As a programmer and SQL novice, I find them easier to read when it's written so verbose, which is also why the tutorial probably used them.